# How to create a function may use custom comparable C++?

Tags: c++, function, templates

I was trying to create a function that needs two compare two objects, but I want it to be usable with any comparable as std::sort works.

In other words, i want this codes to compile in C++

```
bool mycomp(int a, int b) {return a<b;}
int main () {
   deque<int> qu;
   special_push(qu, 3);
   special_push(qu, 5, less<int>());
   special_push(qu, 5, mycomp);
}
```

I have tried so far:

```
template< typename _Compare > void push (deque<int> & qu,int val, _Compare comp = less<int>()) {
    while(qu.empty()==false &&  comp(val, qu.back())) {
      qu.pop_back();
    }
    qu.push_back(val);

}
```

Comment: names starting with double underscore and names starting with underscore and upper letter are reserved to the compiler

Comment: Yeah, i copied that from the compiler

Comment: The compiler implementers are allowed to do that - you are not.

Comment: Thank you, but that code is not for a formal project so doesn't matter than much, but i updated it.

Comment: It matters a lot - using reserved names is a great way of introducing almost impossible to find bugs into your code.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing the obvious typos, the thing you were missing was a default value for the template parameter:

```
#include <deque>
#include <functional>

using std::deque;
using std::less;

bool mycomp(int a, int b) {return a<b;}

template< typename _Compare = std::less<int> >
void special_push (deque<int> & qu,int val, _Compare __comp = less<int>()) {
    while(qu.empty()==false &&  __comp(val, qu.back())) {
      qu.pop_back();
    }
    qu.push_back(val);

}

int main () {
   deque<int> qu;
   special_push(qu, 3);
   special_push(qu, 5, less<int>());
   special_push(qu, 5, mycomp);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an overloaded function (this is often what libstdc++ does internally, but I'm not aware of any reason to do it that way).

Note that there are also several stylistic or pedantic issues you should probably address.

Comment: Don't know what you mean for " 
Note that there are also several stylistic or pedantic issues you should probably address." As English is not my first language

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. All you are missing is a default type for you `Compare`. I also recommend the new `std::less<>` which has a templated operator.

```
template <class Compare = std::less<>>
//                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
auto special_push(std::deque<int> & qu, int val, Compare comp = std::less<>{}) -> void
{
    while(!qu.empty() && comp(val, qu.back()))
    {
      qu.pop_back();
    }
    qu.push_back(val);
}
```